# Use OpenStack HEAT to install and setup MongoDB cluster

Tags: mongodb, openstack, openstack-heat

We need to be able install a MongoDB cluster on OpenStack declaring the number of shards and the size of the replica-set as parameters.

Is there a way to achieve this using a HEAT template, passing in `<shardCount>` and `<replicaSetSize>` as parameters?
Can this be done by HEAT or does it require complicated scripting and on-the-fly template generation?

Comment: Can someone add HEAT or openstack-heat as a tag? I don't have the reputation to do so. Thanks.

Comment: Heat is relatively new and still maturing. I do not think they have mongoDB template still in place. However I found this interesting blueprint. https://blueprints.launchpad.net/trove/+spec/mongodb-support. And also the best place to look of openstack answers is the mailing list.

Comment: @Akilesh thanks, but the template in your link has fixed values. I need a template that will let me provide the sizes as parameters. I would like to use the same template for different sized installations.

Comment: Not any that I know of. Post your question in openstack mailing list they might give you more options.